# Aggregate Return Sub-Grouping as an Array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following MongoDB query:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$Calculation.CustSatisfaction"} // important step!
,{$group: {_id: {country: "$Country",
                 company: "$Company_ID",
                 staff: "$Staff_ID",
                 year: "$Calculation.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Year",
                 mon: "$Calculation.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Month"},
                 tHH: {$sum: "$Calculation.CustSatisfaction.HH"},
                 tHN: {$sum: "$Calculation.CustSatisfaction.HN"}
         }}
 ]);
```

However it will give me multiple rows if there are multiple months. How can I change my query to make it each staff only have a row like below:

```
{
"_id" : {
    "country" : "MY",
    "company" : "MY01",
    "staff" : "NBJ64"
},
"Cust": [ { 
             "year": 2017,
             "month": 9
             "tHH" : 8,
             "tHN" : 0
          },
          { 
             "year": 2017,
             "month": 8
             "tHH" : 7,
             "tHN" : 0,
          }
},
{
"_id" : {
    "country" : "MY",
    "company" : "MY01",
    "staff" : "NBJ50"
},
"Cust": [ { 
             "year": 2017,
             "month": 9
             "tHH" : 1,
             "tHN" : 0
          },
          { 
             "year": 2017,
             "month": 8
             "tHH" : 4,
             "tHN" : 0,
          }
}
```

I am not sure how can I do it.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) the content:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$Calculation.CustSatisfaction" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "country": "$Country",
      "company": "$Company_ID",
      "staff": "$Staff_ID",
      "year": "$Calculation.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Year",
      "month": "$Calculation.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Month"
    },
    "tHH": { "$sum": "$Calculation.CustSatisfaction.HH" },
    "tHN": { "$sum": "$Calculation.CustSatisfaction.HN" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "country": "$_id.counrty",
      "company": "$_id.company",
      "staff": "_id.staff"
    },
    "Cust": {
      "$push": {
        "year": "$_id.year",
        "month": "$_id.month",
        "tHH": "$tHH",
        "tHN": "$tHN"
      }
    }
  }}
]);
```

You are allowed to have multiple [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages in an aggregation pipeline. So your first stage does the general "accumulation" you want, and the second simply "rolls-up" to an array for the common keys.